# API limit during table.getRows; Bigquery + Node.js client

Tags: google-bigquery

Does the limit of 100 API requests per second apply while *paginating* through `table.getRows`?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#apirequests

> API requests per second, per user: If you make more than 100 requests per second, throttling might occur. This limit does not apply for streaming inserts.

I am using the Node client library.

Answer (score 0):

I never investigated this, but as a hint, you could check the [jobs resource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) `cacheHit` boolean parameter on pagination. If this flag is `TRUE` it means it's served from cache, hence no API limits apply.

> Queries that return cached results, or queries configured using the dryRun property, do not count against this limit.

Comment: Not exactly that I was looking for but it was close, thanks anyway. Could you please help me with link for this topic in documents. Because I am looking for details/example about Tabledata::List or Table.getRows using Node.js client?